# can't install ubuntu-software on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-center, dependencies, gnome-software

I did a clean install of 16.04.  When I opened the software center, it showed the categories, but everything inside them was empty, no software was listed, any search turned 0 results.  So I decided I'd reinstall the software center to see if that would help.
Now it won't install:

```
root@adam:~/Downloads# sudo apt-get install ubuntu-software
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-software : Depends: gnome-software (= 3.20.1+git20160420.1.ca63436.ubuntu-xenial-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@adam:~/Downloads# sudo apt-get install gnome-software
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-software : Depends: gnome-software-common (= 3.20.1+git20160420.1.ca63436.ubuntu-xenial-0ubuntu2) but 3.20.1+git20160426.1.a976144-ubuntu-xenial-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@adam:~/Downloads# sudo apt-get install gnome-software-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-software-common is already the newest version (3.20.1+git20160426.1.a976144-ubuntu-xenial-0ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@adam:~/Downloads#
```

Comment: Oh, just did "apt-get install gnome-software-common=3.20.1+git20160420.1.ca63436.ubuntu-xenial-0ubuntu2" and it worked, went back through each package, all installed now

Answer (score 0):

If you have any trouble like that again I would try sudo apt-get update , and then sudo apt-get -f install it should fix most dependencies problems.

Comment: I had tried that, but it gave a message about the dependency not going to be installed.  It's like the latest version wasn't given the option of using a newer dependency, and it wouldn't install the older one for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

Gnome Software is just like the old Ubuntu Software Center. It's a bit lazy on first run. It loads kinda slow. Just close it and open it again. It will load up the apps list eventually. It happens to me too. All the time. But i still prefer it over the Ubuntu Software Center. It definitely runs faster. Some apps still missing from it, probably because they don't have xenial sources yet. It's a radical change for Ubuntu and it's still very new, it will get smoother in time.